# Angular 11 async validator triggering endless loop of requests on true response

Tags: angular, forms, validation, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

So, I'm creating a simple registration form with an async existing user validation, which executes a http request to my API that returns a boolean for existing user.

**The component**:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserTakenValidatorService } from '../../services/user-taken.validator.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.less'],
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  public signupForm: FormGroup;
  public hide = true;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private checkUserTaken: UserTakenValidatorService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      fullName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(40)]],
      userName: [
        '',
        [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)],
        this.checkUserTaken.checkUserNameTaken(),
      ],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
    });
  }

  signup() {
    console.log(this.signupForm.controls.userName.errors);
  }
}
```

And this is the **validator**:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import {  map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserTakenValidatorService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  checkUserNameTaken() {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {             
      return this.verifyUsername(control.value)
        .pipe(map((isTaken) => (isTaken ? { userNameTaken: true } : null)))
    };
  }

  private verifyUsername(userName: string) {
    return this.http.get<boolean>(`${API_URL}/user/exists/${userName}`);
  }
}
```

This has been triggering an endless loop of requests when inputting an existing user (i.e. on **true** responses from API) that also don't add errors to `signupForm.controls.userName.errors` and that stops on the first false response.

P.S.: Dependencies are `@angular/core/forms/common 11.0.0` and `rxjs 6.6.0`

Answer (score 1):

The Angular HttpClient expects a JSON per default. It seems your response contains a string only, which represents a boolean.

Please try the following

```
private verifyUsername(userName: string) {
    return this.http.get<string>(`${API_URL}/user/exists/${userName}`, { responseType: 'text' }).pipe(
      map(stringBoolean => stringBoolean === 'true'),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I deleted my previous comment cause on a more thorough analysis, even though it throws an weird "No overload matches this call" (which is in Angular documentation as Overload #3), it does compile returning a `string` that keeps triggering the loop. Changing to `{ responseType: 'json' }` (Overload #15) appeared to work, but type of response came as `boolean`, thus always returning `false` on the map condition; trying to remove it, brought back the loop.